# iphone calculator keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikeyboardtype

I am pretty new to iPhone development, so I don't know if this is even possible, but is it possible to customize a keyboard so it looks like a calculator? I know how to use `inputAccessoryView` to put buttons on top of the keyboard, but I would like to put the add, multiply, divide and subtract buttons on the side to make it look like a more standard calculator. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a whole replacement "keyboard" with your own buttons and actions to do this. This will be a UIView holding a set of UIButtons. If you want this to pop up like the regular keyboard (as opposed to being on screen all the time like in the calculator app) then set your new view to be the `inputView` of your text field rather than the `inputAccessoryView`.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Buttons

Check out [CodePadawan: iPhone Glossy Buttons](http://www.codepadawan.com/2011/06/iphone-glossy-buttons.html) for programmatically created calculator buttons.

However, I would suggest using PNG images for the button backgrounds. You can extract the normal button backgrounds (I didn't find selected button background.) from [iPhone UI Vector Elements](http://www.mercuryintermedia.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/iphone-ui-vector-elements) (linked to from [iPhone and iPad Development GUI Kits, Stencils and Icons](http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/30/iphone-and-ipad-development-gui-kits-stencils-and-icons/)) with Adobe Illustrator by making a selection, copy, new, paste, Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art > Save for Web.

*CalculatorMemoryButtonBackgroundNormal.png* & *CalculatorMemoryButtonBackgroundNormal@2x.png*

[image: calculator memory button background normal]
[image: calculator memory button background normal retina]

*CalculatorOperatorButtonBackgroundNormal.png* & *CalculatorOperatorButtonBackgroundNormal@2x.png*

[image: calculator operator button background normal]
[image: calculator operator button background normal retina]

*CalculatorDigitButtonBackgroundNormal.png* & *CalculatorDigitButtonBackgroundNormal@2x.png*

[image: calculator digit button background normal]
[image: calculator digit button background normal retina]

*CalculatorEqualButtonBackgroundNormal.png* & *CalculatorEqualButtonBackgroundNormal@2x.png*

[image: calculator equal button background normal]
[image: calculator equal button background normal retina]

#### The Implementation

- [How to create a custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643167/iphone-objc-how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to iPhone Application Development, I would say go to Youtube and watch tutorials on iPhone app dev, and it is of great resource. As for your "Calculator" project - visit [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaE5z12nlyA)  !

Answer (score 1):

Not in any simple way. Given how simple this keyboard would be, this is better achieved by building a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Custom iPhone Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard)

However, it is possible that Apple could reject your app according to various SO posts on the issue.