# custom Keyboard make for an app in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I am developing an application, in which i need 3 keyboard which should looks like iPhone default keyboard like F1, F2...f12, Navigational Button, Commands buttons so my questions are.

1. Is this possible that i can use iPhone keyboard and edit or add extra-function or any other API given to extend keyboard functionality?
2. Should i make my own keyboard like add `UIView` and add buttons?
3. If i use my own, will apple accept my app for uploading on iTunes?
   Please clear my and if any helping material you've then kindly share with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible that i can use iPhone keyboard and edit or add
>   extra-function or any other API given to extend keyboard
>   functionality?

You can extend it by adding additional view on the upper side of it, like a toolbar with additional buttons, that will not be inside the keyboard but only over it

> Should i make my own keyboard like add UIView and add buttons?

You can create a custom keyboard, like the one used in calculator apps and so, it could be a uiview with custom keys

> If i use my own, will apple accept my app for uploading on iTunes?
>   Please clear my and if any helping material you've then kindly share
>   with me. Thanks in advance.

If your custom keyboard is not misleading and is done in a proper way then it should not be rejected, 
read the following [Custom iPhone Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no api that providing extra features and functionality for iPhone native Keyboard
2. You can make your own keyboard using `VSKeypadView`
3. Apple will accept the application as there are many applications implemented custom keyboard in the app store

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that UITextView and UITextField both have optional variables of the form:

```
public var inputView: UIView?
public var inputAccessoryView: UIView?
```

You should do further research in how to use them. I think in particular inputAccessoryView into which you'd put your extra buttons.