# how to make a keyboard in other language in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype, uikeyinput

I want to create a khmer keyboard which is different from iPhone keyboard. How can I do that ?

Comment: **[whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**?

Comment: Settings -> General -> International -> Keyboards

Comment: I want to add this keyboard to my program and I don't want to make users difficult to use by changing language like this. users will see this keyboard when they search the products. Do you know what parts should we code to make keyboard similar to this ? I just want the letters, not number !

Comment: I don't want user to change language as a whole in iphone; I just want this keyboard for an app.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot control the language of the keyboard. The user chooses which keyboards they would like available via the settings application and can toggle between them using the globe icon on the keyboard. When the keyboard is opened it will open to the most recently used keyboard.

Comment: default keyboards are numberpad, number with puctuation, ,...but I don't want those keyboard because I do a project that will be used by cambodian , not English !

Comment: Do you know how to customize keyboard ?

Comment: follow this link...  http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/

Answer (score 2):

make a customize keyboard. take a UIView add UIButton and add what you want to all in this view.

Comment: after adding uibutton to uiview , how can we call it to use ?

Comment: hope this link help ful for you...    http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/ .... And sample app link is...  https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad

Comment: If I design keyboard in nib file, how can I call it to use ?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from iOS 4, UITextField and UITextView have a property called inputView. It should be a view able to receive the taps and send to the UIViewController that holds your text field. So, can create a UIViewController with delegate methods, and set it's view as the inputView of your UITextField or UITextView. So, assuming that MyCustomKeyboard is the UIViewController that is your keyboard, including the view and the delegate methods, in your viewDidLoad of your view controller, you should put:

```
MyCustomKeyboard *customKeyboard = [[MyCustomKeyboard alloc] init];
customKeyboard.delegate = self;
myTextField.inputView = customKeyboard.view;
```

And in your view controller you handle the delegate methods of your MyCustomKeyboard class.

If you want a tutorial, [there is a good one in Ray Wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial), you should do something similar to the iPhone.

Comment: I don't want to use another view! I try this already, but my company doesn't accept it !

Comment: You don't have other approved/public option my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done just for one app, two options:

- The user has to change to the correct language.

Since that is not what you want, there is option 2:

- Implement your own keyboard (=huge amount of work)

Comment: Yes! Option 2 is so hard, but I have to do !