# how to customize key board in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make a keyboard in other language in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192818/how-to-make-a-keyboard-in-other-language-in-ios)

I want to do a keyboard that has interface like the picture below. How can I do like this ?

[image: khmer keyboard]